# How to return List<E> from Collection<V> where E is contained inside V?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a map which returns below data when `Map.values()` is called which returns `Collection<V>`

```java
[
    Cache.CachedObject(inserted=1617483447407, value=Record(id=10, type=5, timestamp=2021-04-03T08:37:51.312Z)), 
    Cache.CachedObject(inserted=1617483446133, value=Record(id=11, type=6, timestamp=2021-04-03T08:37:51.312Z)), 
    Cache.CachedObject(inserted=1617483445030, value=Record(id=8, type=4, timestamp=2021-04-03T08:37:51.312Z))
]
```

How do I return `List<Record>` from `Collection<V>` ?

Code of Cache class is given below

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//

package com.api.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Cache<K, V> {
    private long timeToLive = 20000L;
    private HashMap<K, V> cacheMap = new HashMap();

    public Cache() {
        if (this.timeToLive > 0L) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                while(true) {
                    this.cleanup();
                }
            });
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        }

    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            this.cacheMap.put(key, new Cache.CachedObject(value));
        }
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            Cache<K, V>.CachedObject c = (Cache.CachedObject)this.cacheMap.get(key);
            return c == null ? null : c.value;
        }
    }

    public void remove(K key) {
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            this.cacheMap.remove(key);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            return this.cacheMap.size();
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            this.cacheMap.clear();
        }
    }

    public Collection<V> values() {
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            return this.cacheMap.values();
        }
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList deleteKey;
        synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
            Iterator<Entry<K, V>> itr = this.cacheMap.entrySet().iterator();
            deleteKey = new ArrayList(this.cacheMap.size() / 2 + 1);

            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Entry<K, V> entry = (Entry)itr.next();
                K key = entry.getKey();
                V cached = entry.getValue();
                if (cached != null && now > ((Cache.CachedObject)cached).inserted + this.timeToLive) {
                    deleteKey.add(key);
                }
            }
        }

        for(Iterator var4 = deleteKey.iterator(); var4.hasNext(); Thread.yield()) {
            K key = var4.next();
            synchronized(this.cacheMap) {
                this.cacheMap.remove(key);
            }
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Cache(timeToLive=" + this.timeToLive + ", cacheMap=" + this.cacheMap + ")";
    }

    private class CachedObject {
        public long inserted = System.currentTimeMillis();
        public V value;

        protected CachedObject(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Cache.CachedObject(inserted=" + this.getInserted() + ", value=" + this.getValue() + ")";
        }

        public long getInserted() {
            return this.inserted;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `Cache.CachedObject` sources?

Comment: The code of `Cache` does not compile and is abundant of errors, to this was definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because CachedObject was not declared as generic, and the inner map does not have `V` type for its values but `CachedObject<V>`, and this must be changed just to make the code compile.  Abundant `synchronized` blocks should be replaced with a thread-safe map such as `ConcurrentHashMap` or at least by applying `Collections.synchronizedMap`

Comment: @AlexRudenko Not sure what errors you got. You're right about design issues. This is one of the library class, I now implemented my own. However reason given to me for synchronized blocks instead of some thread safe collection is that the cache retrieval should be I constant time. I have little doubt about it though. Anyway thanks a lot for pushing me in right direction.

Comment: The errors that appear immediately: method `Cache::put`: `incompatible types: Cache.CachedObject cannot be converted to V
            this.cacheMap.put(key, new Cache.CachedObject(value));`
method `Cache::cleanUp`: `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to K
            K key = var4.next();`

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

To resolve multiple compilation and design issues in the posted code of `Cache /CachedObject`, the following fixes need to be applied (but they are not final and further improvements are possible):

- Make inner class `CachedObject` generic
- Replace `HashMap` with `ConcurrentHashMap` (so that `synchronized` blocks could be removed) and fix the type of value in this map to be `CachedObject<V>`
- Refactor `cleanUp` method

An example implementation

```java
public class Cache<K, V> {
    private long timeToLive = 20000L;
    private Map<K, CachedObject<V>> cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Cache() {
        if (this.timeToLive > 0L) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                while(true) {
                    this.cleanup();
                }
            });
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        this.cacheMap.put(key, new CachedObject(value));
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        CachedObject<V> c = this.cacheMap.get(key);
        return c == null ? null : c.value;
    }

    public void remove(K key) {
        this.cacheMap.remove(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.cacheMap.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.cacheMap.clear();
    }

    public Collection<V> values() {
        return this.cacheMap.values().stream()
            .map(CachedObject::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        if (!this.cacheMap.isEmpty()) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.cacheMap.entrySet().removeIf(e -> null == e.getValue() || now > e.getValue().inserted + this.timeToLive);
        }
        Thread.yield();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Cache(timeToLive=" + this.timeToLive + ", cacheMap=" + this.cacheMap + ")";
    }

    private class CachedObject<V> {
        public long inserted = System.currentTimeMillis();
        public V value;

        protected CachedObject(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Cache.CachedObject(inserted=" + this.getInserted() + ", value=" + this.getValue() + ")";
        }

        public long getInserted() {
            return this.inserted;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

With this implementation, the method `Cache::values()` provides an appropriate collection of `V`-type elements which are copied into a list, so it will be sufficient just to cast to `List`:

```java
Cache<String, Record> cache = new Cache<>();
cache.put("#1", new Record(1));
cache.put("#2", new Record(2));
cache.put("#3", new Record(3));

System.out.println(cache);

List<Record> records = (List<Record>) cache.values();
System.out.println(records);

System.out.println(records);

Thread.sleep(2_100L);

List<Record> noRecords = (List) cache.values();
System.out.println(noRecords);
```

Output

```
Cache(timeToLive=2000, cacheMap={#3=Cache.CachedObject(inserted=1617530470001, value=Record{id=3}), #1=Cache.CachedObject(inserted=1617530470001, value=Record{id=1}), #2=Cache.CachedObject(inserted=1617530470001, value=Record{id=2})})
[Record{id=3}, Record{id=1}, Record{id=2}]
[]
```

Comment: Tries this, it returns the log i provided. Actually the "value" inside CachedObject is a generic. `public V getValue() {return this.value;}` . Tried multiple things to extract but failing

Comment: `.map(CachedObject::getValue).map(Record.class::cast)` then.

Comment: @AshishDeshpande I don't see any log nor the code of `CachedObject`.  Is it used as `CachedObject<Record>`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko code provided.

@JoopEggen Tried that too getting ```reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that V conforms to Cache<K, V>.CachedObject``` getting compile time error, required ```Required type: Function  Provided: <method reference>```

Comment: @AshishDeshpande the entire class Cache has multiple design issues in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [**Eclipse Collections**](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (which is a great library by the way, an extra dependency however...) , you might want to use the following

```
List<String> valuesList = Lists.mutable
                               .ofAll(values)
                               .collect(CachedObject::getValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Decided to implement library Cache<K, V> class with minor change to values method.

```java
public Collection<V> values() {
        synchronized (cacheMap) {
            return cacheMap
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .map(cache -> ((CachedObject) cache).getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Can someone please conform if its the right way